# Newly installed theme on sugarcrm tabs not functioning

Tags: sugarcrm

I am trying to install Modern Aqua theme on SugarCRM 6.4.0. But few tabs are not functioning. If I enable the default theme it simply works fine. Could you please help me how to fix the this issue?

I have copied Modern Aqua theme to /theme/ directory on sugarcrm root folder. Then I have modified the themedef.php same as default theme themedef.php file.

Then I have renamed the default theme from Sugar5 to Sugar5_off

Then I have modified the config.php file variable as below:

## 'default_theme' => 'ModernAqua',

Done!

It simply loads great for me with new installed theme. But the thing is all Menu tabs are not functioning. Only Calender, Documents, Email & campaign tabs are working. Other tabs like Home, Leads, opportunities, Contacts, Accounts etc. are not working. If I click on the tabs nothing will reflect.

Could you please assist me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, one work-around is to disable jquery for the modules in `config_override.php` but I do not think this is the best option, there must be another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Modern Aqua is compatible with 6.4.0 anymore, so it probably needs some work to have it back functioning properly.